# CAGradientLayer autorotation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, cagradientlayer

I use CAGradientLayer to generate this thin line gradient. The problem is autorotation is not smooth. As the UIViewController rotates, I set then frame of this view containing this layer in viewDidLayoutSubviews and reset the frame of this layer. The line grows in height as I autorotate and the gradient is from top to bottom for some time in rotation. What is the correct way to autorotate this layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting out of the business of adjusting the sublayer in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Instead, I’d let auto layout do this for you.

- First, define `GradientView` that will render the `CAGradientLayer`:

  ```
  class GradientView: UIView {
      // specify that the base layer should be gradient layer

      override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
          return CAGradientLayer.self
      }

      // it can be convenient to have computed property that returns layer of the `layerClass`

      private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
          return layer as! CAGradientLayer
      }

      // when we update our array of colors, update the gradient layer accordingly

      var colors: [UIColor] = [] {
          didSet {
              gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
          }
      }

      // initializers

      override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          configure()
      }

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
          configure()
      }

      // configure the view for horizontal gradient

      private func configure() {
          colors = [.red, .yellow, .green, .blue]
          gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
          gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
      }
  }
  ```

  By specifying the [`layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass) of this subview, you don’t have to worry about resizing issues. Resize the view as needed, and the layer will automatically be resized accordingly.
- Then, just add the constraints for your new view, and let auto layout take care of the configuration. E.g.

  ```
  let gradientView = GradientView()
  gradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  view.addSubview(gradientView)

  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      gradientView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
      gradientView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
      gradientView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
      gradientView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3)
  ])
  ```

Now, clearly, use whatever constraints that work for you, but hopefully this illustrates the idea. Let auto layout configure the `frame` of the view, and let because the `layerClass` is `CAGradientLayer`, it will get updated automatically for you.

Comment: Ok I did implement a GradientView, but the issue is height is not a constant. In portrait mode, height is say 3 points and in landscape mode, width is 3 points. Then I see autorotation issues. This one has got nothing to do with GradientView, seems a generic issue and same as I reported in this question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389933/uiview-autorotation-issue

Comment: OK, that’s a different question. There are a couple of possible approaches to that, which I’ve outlined there...