# UIView autorotation issue

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, size-classes, autorotate

I am getting issues in autorotation of a UIView which is nothing but a red line of width 4 and height half of superview's height in landscape mode, and in portrait mode the height is 4 points and width is half of superview width. You can see the issue in the gif. As I rotate from landscape to portrait, the effect of autorotation is not smooth and with distortions.

[image]

Here is the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
private var myView:UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/2, height: 4))
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(myView)

    myView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width/2, y: view.bounds.height/2)


}

private func layoutMyView() {

    let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

    if orientation == .landscapeLeft || orientation == .landscapeRight {
        myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width/2, height: 4)
    } else {
        myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 4, height: view.bounds.height/2)
    }

    myView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width/2, y: view.bounds.height/2)
}


override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

    NSLog("View will transition to \(size), \(orientation.rawValue)")

    if size.width < size.height {
        NSLog("Portrait mode")
    } else {
        NSLog("Landscape mode")
    }

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { [unowned self] (_) in

        let orient = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

         self.layoutMyView()

        }, completion: { [unowned self] (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

            let orient = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
            self.layoutMyView()
            NSLog("rotation completed to \(orient.rawValue), \(self.myView.frame)")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few potential options:

1. In `animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)`, do a keyframe animation to set mid animation point so you don’t end up with that curious boxy feel mid animation. E.g. this shrink it down to a 4x4 box

   ```
   override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
       super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

       let origin = CGPoint(x: (view.bounds.midX + view.bounds.midY) / 2 - 2,
                            y: (view.bounds.midX + view.bounds.midY) / 2 - 2)

       coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
           UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: coordinator.transitionDuration, delay: 0, animations: {
               UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                   self.myView.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4))
               }

               UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                   self.layoutMyView()
               }
           })
       })
   }
   ```

   There are many possible variations on this theme. This still animates the view, but gives it a more “deliberate” sort of vibe and doesn’t lose the “line” feel of it.

   [image]
2. Rather than rendering a “line” with `UIView`, use [`CAShapeLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer) and update its [`path`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521904-path).
3. You could run a [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) while transition is in progress, and then update the frame to whatever you want as the animation progresses.
4. Instead of animating the `frame`, you could animate the `transform` of this view, possibly rotating it in the opposite direction that the view is rotating.